# Install google analytics in local url

Tags: url, configuration, installation, localhost, analytics

Is possible install/add Google Analytics to localhost project for do some test???

I already created an account in Google Analytics but I am not sure what that I need to write in the URL field...

I tried with 127.0.0.1/myFolder an localhost too.

Comment: Which field are you referring to? The one in Property Settings? View Settings? If it's either of those, it doesn't really matter. The URL is used only in reporting.

Comment: It is in property settings. I want to do some test with the reporting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is ignore the domain when you want to test it locally.

You can do it adding this code to the generated google script:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-X']);
    _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);
```